# 2D wavelet filtering in python on an image

Tags: python, image, filtering, wavelet-transform, pywavelets

I'm trying to do 2d wavelet filtering in python. I found out about PyWavelets and I have been messing around with it for awhile. I am trying to do the transformation for 4 levels. When I print it out it gives werid output and I'm not sure exactly what is going on. I've tried a few things but this is the latest as an example:

```
test = pywt.dwt2(picture,'db1')
```

Any help on preforming 2d wavelets on images with PyWavelets or just in general would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: The type of wavelet transformation doesn't matter

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain what exactly is the weird output?
you should get output vector with cA,cL,cH and cD coefficients.
If you want to view the transform domain image, arrange the coefficients like below:
cA, (cH, cV, cD)

length of output vector = rows x columns of the input image
(provided you have a square image)

If you want to view a lower resolution image, arrange the first 1/4th elements (cA) in the output vector in square format. Currently, they will be like
[Row 1, Row2, Row3...]
Also, are you giving level parameter (optional) in pywt.dwt2 command?

Refer this http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/ref/2d-dwt-and-idwt.html

Comment: Please can you explain in python code what you mean by `[cA cL; cH cD]` ?

Comment: cA, (cH, cV, cD) is the output.. here, cA is the approximated low-resolution image left after decomposing wavelet coefficients at that level. Others are wavelet coefficients extracted by the filter Horizontally (cH), Vertically(cV), and Diagonally(cD)

Comment: Here you can see how horizontal, vertical, and diagonal image. https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

The entire idea behind the wavelet transform of images is to give the domain analysis of the signal in terms of both frequency and time, which the discrete Fourier transform failed to provide. The 4 outputs of the function i.e., [cA cV; cH cD] the 4 approximate subbands that offer a multi-resolution view of the image:

cA (Approximation Subband): Low-frequency components, obtained through low-pass filters, provide a lower-resolution image approximation.

cV (Vertical Detail Subband): Captures high-frequency vertical components, useful for detecting vertical edges and fine details.

cH (Horizontal Detail Subband): Similar to cV but for horizontal components, aiding in identifying horizontal edges and features.

cD (Diagonal Detail Subband): Represents high-frequency diagonal components, obtained through high-pass filters, highlighting diagonal edges and features.

Below is a Python code that will give you an idea of the functioning, but it's not exactly wavelets.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv.imread('/content/diamond.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

def conv(image, filter):
  dimx = image.shape[0]-filter.shape[0]+1
  dimy = image.shape[1]-filter.shape[1]+1
  ans = np.zeros((dimx,dimy))
  for i in range(dimx):
    for j in range(dimy):
      ans[i,j] = np.sum(image[i:i+filter.shape[0],j:j+filter.shape[1]]*filter)
  return ans


def dwt(image):
  lowpass = np.ones((3,3))*(1/9)
  highpass_x = np.array([[1,0,-1],[2,0,-2],[1,0,-1]])#sobel filter
  highpass_y = np.array([[1,2,1],[0,0,0],[-1,-2,-1]])#sobel filter
  l = conv(image, lowpass)
  h = conv(image,highpass_x)
  ll = conv(l,lowpass)#approximate subband
  lh = conv(l,highpass_x)#horizontal subband
  hl = conv(l,highpass_y)#vertical subband
  hh = conv(h,highpass_y)#diagonal subband
  return ll, lh, hl, hh

ll0, lh0, hl0 ,hh0 = dwt(image)

plt.figure(figsize=(5,4))
plt.subplot(2,2,1), plt.imshow(ll0, cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(2,2,2), plt.imshow(lh0, cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(2,2,3), plt.imshow(hl0, cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(2,2,4), plt.imshow(hh0, cmap='gray')
```

it will give an output like this:

[this shows the cA,cV,cH,cD subbands of the initial image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xCKF.png)