# How to perform lowpass filtering in RGB images with Discrete Wavelet Transform in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, filtering, wavelet-transform

I am trying to implement the following paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11042-011-0835-9

In this paper, the authors say the following: [image]

It seems that the authors filter the image with a lowpass DWT filter and then subtract the original image with the filtered one, the outputs are supposed to be the following:

[image]

So, my questions are:

1. How to perform DWT 2D lowpass filtering with Python? should I generate a mask with DWT coefficients and convolve it with images? if yes, how to generate such a mask and do this operation? I checked [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057765/2d-wavelet-filtering-in-python-on-an-image) but it does not help me. Basically the approximation of the DWT has a lower resolution than the input image and **therefore I cant subtract them**. So, the topic of this previous question is useless to my problem here.
2. I need that the filtered image must be in RGB too. How can I achieve that? filtering channel by channel or there is another smart way to do that?

Comment: See SKIMAGE wavelet denoting at https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/filters/plot_denoise_wavelet.html